# PHP Function add Font Awesome integrity key to css file

Tags: php, function, font-awesome

I'm using a function to call the css library for font awesome, I'd like to include the integrity key to make sure the file is secure.

> integrity="sha384-xxx" crossorigin="anonymous"

Would something like the following work?

```
function jsScripts() {

$integrity = 'integrity="sha384-xxx"';
$crossorigin = 'crossorigin="anonymous"';

      wp_enqueue_script( 'fontawesome', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css', $integrity, $crossorigin );

    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','jsScripts');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `wp_script_add_data`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_script_add_data/

Here's an example.

https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/wp_script_add_data/php-wp_script_add_data-function-examples.html

Please refer the following answer for more options.

[Wordpress script with integrity and crossorigin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827134/wordpress-script-with-integrity-and-crossorigin)

Comment: Awesome, Thank you :)

Comment: Also consider the forthcoming official Font Awesome WordPress plugin to improve compatibility across plugins and themes.

The plugin handles integrity and crossorigin for you, among other things.

https://github.com/FortAwesome/wordpress-fontawesome